# Magicsuggest - How to display selected item with a different label than the suggestion?

Tags: magicsuggest

So here's the scenario. 
The user can search people by either name or phone number. I like the fact that in the suggestions dropdown, it shows the person's name and phone number... and the text highlighting that goes with it.
However, once they select the person, I want only the person's name to show in the selection. Not the phone number.
Is there a way I can override a label/display function for selected items?

NOTE: I already have a different value/id field.  So this needs to be completely independent of that.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Am I the only one here using MagicSuggest?
Anyway... the answer is to set a custom selectionRenderer in the declaraion.

selectionRenderer: function(obj){return obj["shortName"];}